# Referenced assemblies returns None as ProcessorArchitecture

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, 64-bit, cpu-architecture

I have a web project who's DLL I load using `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(filename)`. I then call `assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies();`.

The returned `AssemblyName`s all have the `ProcessorArchitecture` set to `None`.

The primary DLL's ProcessorArchitecture is x64 while references vary between AnyCPU and x64.

Any idea why I'm not able to pick up the ProcessorArchitecture for these references assemblies?

**UPDATE:** I just saw this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.processorarchitecture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) stating:

> Beginning with the .NET Framework 4, this property always returns ProcessorArchitecture.None for reference assemblies.

Is there another way to get to this information?

Comment: Have you tried [Module.GetPEKind()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.module.getpekind(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem; the code which I ended up using was something like the following:

```
static void Main() {
    // Load assembly. This can either be by name, or by calling GetReferencedAssemblies().
    Assembly referencedAssembly = Assembly.Load("AssemblyName");

    // Get the PEKind for the assembly, and handle appropriately
    PortableExecutableKinds referenceKind = GetPEKinds(referencedAssembly);
    if((referenceKind & PortableExecutableKinds.Required32Bit) > 0) {
        // is 32 bit assembly
    }
    else if((referenceKind & PortableExecutableKinds.PE32Plus) > 0) {
        // is 64 bit assembly
    }
    else if((referenceKind & PortableExecutableKinds.ILOnly) > 0) {
        // is AnyCpu
    }
}

static PortableExecutableKinds GetPEKinds(Assembly assembly) {
    PortableExecutableKinds peKinds;
    ImageFileMachine imageFileMachine;
    assembly.GetModules()[0].GetPEKind(out peKinds, out imageFileMachine);
    return peKinds;
}
```